# Flying from London to Copenhagen?

Tags: uk, london, covid-19, ireland, denmark

I need to travel from London to Copenhagen for a job interview. It is likely that they will hire me, so it's not just for the interview, I would fly and remain there indefinitely.

Since the UK banned all the flights, my best option is to fly to London-Dublin (stop over for 2 hours) and then fly Dublin-Copenhagen.

My plan is at arrival in Copenhagen's airport, to take the test (they have a test center).  The airport states in their website   https://www.cph.dk/en/practical/travel-safely-through-copenhagen-airport   "A service provider has facilitated a test facility in Pier E and in Pier C, so that passengers arriving without a valid test result can be tested. This test can then be used for documentation at the border control".

(I have a Spanish passport).

Will I have any troubles in London, Dublin or Copenhagen?

Comment: Noe that the UK banned flights **from** Denmark, but not **to** Denmark. Most airlines fly the same route back and forth, but some have more complex routings apparently, since there seem to be a few flights left from London to Copenhagen, including a Ryanair flight this Sunday and an SAS flight on Monday. Also, I would expect at least some airlines to require a test before letting you board, though I have no idea if this is the case in this specific situation. If you flight through a third city, I hope you plan to do that on a single ticket and not separate bookings.

Comment: Per what I checked Ryanair also cancelled the flights to Denmark... (not only from..)

Comment: Ryanair’s website says there’s a flight on Sunday from Luton to Copenhagen. Very cheap, too (10 pounds right now). Don’t know if it’ll actually fly or if they just forgot to remove it from the site. Google flights also has an SAS flight on Monday IIRC.

Comment: Eurostar is running, as are international trains within the EU.  Some countries require tests for entering but not for transiting.  Just get a test before you set off, then take the train?

Comment: Not sure why they sell that flight... they clearly say that they are not flying  https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/travel-updates/articles/ryanair-calls-on-transport-minister-grant-shapps-to-reverse-idio

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.